# Single most powerful weapon in the 40k universe.

Tags: warhammer-40k

Is there one single weapon in 40k that is head and shoulders above the rest?

In my mind the d-cannon has no limits on its power. But this can only effect a small area, I'm thinking more weapons that exists but can't be used in the game.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While Cyclonic Torpedoes are pretty powerful, there is something far more dangerous: The Celestial Orrery, built and owned by the Necrons.

It's basically a real-time 3D holographic map of the entire galaxy, that allows for physical interaction. If you were to move a planet or snuff out one of the star lights, a similar fate would immediately beset the real thing. A Necron could destroy the heart of the Imperium in one move by snuffing out the light representing Terra (or her star, Sol) and causing the annihilation of the Emperor, the Imperial Palace, et cetera.

You can imagine the devastation if someone accidentally trips in this thing.

Entry from the Necrons 5th Edition Codex:

[image: Thanatos and the Celestial Orrery]

Comment: This sounds like a winner.

Comment: Yeah, I'd have to agree, this one takes the cake!

Comment: I wonder what would happen if Thanatos was hit by an Exterminatus, Planet killer, or otherwise destroyed

Answer (score 7):

When [Exterminatus](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Exterminatus) has been declared on a planet that has pissed off the [Inquisition](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Inquisition), they usually use [Cyclonic torpedoes](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Cyclonic_torpedo) to obliterate the entire world.

A [tyranid Hive Ship](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Hive_Ship) could also be considered... while not necessarily a weapon in the same vein as a gun or bomb, it's really just a huge tyranid. And tyranids themselves are living breathing weapons.

[image]

In the Warhammer 40k universe, I don't think there is really any [ultimate handheld weapon](http://www.wowwiki.com/Sword_of_a_Thousand_Truths_(South_Park)), at least not in anything I've read. Most famous weapons, like [Gorechild](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Kh%C3%A2rn_the_Betrayer) and [Gorefather](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Angron) for example, gain their reputation from the guys that wield them.

There is always [Anathame](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Anathame), the knife that almost killed Horus. But then that knife wouldn't be much used against a cyclonic torpedo...

Comment: Interestedly they are all Imperium weapons. Thats some bomb!

Comment: @JamieHutber I updated my answer... Nids perhaps?

Comment: To be honest, the only tool for Exterminatus that I wouldn't consider equally powerful would be sustained orbital bombardment by conventional artillery (which I believe was only used for Exterminatus once). Does it _really_ matter if you crack the crust vs. ignite the atmosphere, for example?

Comment: @BrianS From the Inquisitons's point of view, when dealing with Chaos, you have to literally wipe out every living organism. There's no such thing as overkill with those fellas.

Comment: The Hive Ship itself isn't the weapon, though - it's more like the delivery system.

Comment: @Omegacron I think a hive ship is much more than that. The link above explains it very well.

Comment: @DAft - Ah, I see what you're saying. I was looking at it like the nids were a virus (the actual weapon) & the hive ship was the syringe.

Comment: @Omegacron You raise a valid point, a case could be made that Tyranids are one huge biological weapon themselves. Gaunts and hive ships included.

Comment: What about the necron world engine? that thing cleared out several worlds before it was stopped by imperial forces. and the tyranids aren't that keen on consuming necrons

Comment: @svarog yeah I didn't think of that. So for arguments sake, if the deadliest weapon in the galaxy is a [Tyranid Hive Fleet](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Hive_Fleet_Behemoth), the Necrons have absolutely nothing to fear from them...

Comment: If the Tyranids are a weapon, then the Orks too. They have been engineered by the Old Ones for their war, and are basically a biological weapon gone out of control.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the weapons already mentioned in answers there are two more:

### [Planet Killer](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Killer)

It does not extinguish the live on a planet but the whole planet itself:

[image: Planet Killer]

### [Blackstone Fortress](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Blackstone_Fortress)

These weapons were able to destroy a complete solar system with a single blast (I think two or three of them combined their power). They were originally built by the Eldar. It is unknown though what their maximum power would have looked like if all of the Blackstone Fortresses had combined their firepower, as most of them got destroyed before that could happen.

[image: Blackstone Fortress]

Comment: Thats pretty dam powerful tbh lol

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd add this in since its not been mentioned yet and is by fair in a way more powerful than the Exterminatus!

There are spoilers here if you haven't read the book *Velador*.

---

I present the [Fireheart](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Fireheart) `Dun dun darhhh!!!`:

This weapon has a powerful shield blocking others from deactivated it. It was a relic from the past Eldar glory days.

Upon receiving the fireheart:

> His impossibly wide grin grew wider. "Well, unless circumstances necessitate. Anyway, the nature of the problem was presented to us by the dancing fools, that you lacked a weapon of sufficient potency to incinerate the planet properly. My Lord Vect, in his infinite wisdom, proceeded directly to his grand armoury and produced this." Sarnak’s awful face disappeared, and a monolithic device, tall as a Revenant, took its place. Gems studded its sides at regular intervals, one of great size mounted on its summit. "Behold!" he said pompously. "The Fireheart. A device of the elder days, when our kind strode the Great Wheel as masters over all, and didn’t live such dreary, funless little lives on boring worldlets. It’s in the hold of my ship, waiting just for you. Aren’t we nice?" He giggled.

The device can be activated from anywhere by powerful seers. All the Eldar needed to do is deploy the Fireheart to the planet.

> "The Shadow," said Taec bluntly. His vision flickered through his mind’s eye, he on the surface of a world tearing itself apart by a monumental device, and falling to be burned, his soul consumed. "It will prevent remote activation."

Its not small.

> Tall among them was the building-sized Fireheart.

It effectively goes into the planet's soul and wrecks it. Destroying it from the inside out.

> Place it there, and the Fireheart will consume the planet and its dead soul.

and

> The machine directed their minds and amplified them, pushing their strength down, down into the rock. Taec and the seers went with the Fireheart as its semi-sentient core sought the fault that had once fed the eruptions of the Godpeak. It thrust down, past a domed magma chamber empty of heat, through plugged tubes that had once rushed with molten rock, down, down to the mantle, whose currents of molten stone were as yet unperturbed by the war on the surface.

Again its old and looks bloody brilliant.

> Taec looked up at the Fireheart. It was old, as old as the ancient empire. The architecture of it was neither that of Commorragh nor that of the craftworlds, but somewhere between the two.

Basically this is fantastic and I think can be up there with the most powerful weapons. It destroyed the planet in half a day or so. So if you deployed it in the correct positions, the inhabitants wouldn't even have enough time to counter it.

Answer (score -1):

[Cyclonic torpedoes](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Cyclonic_torpedo). Used for Exterminatus!

They can destroy ALL life from orbital bombardment.